# Can't create a backup of data of a single table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I try to use a command:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d "ProjectsManagement" -t public.Statuses -a > path
```

But it doesn't work and outputs:

> pg_dump: соответствующие таблицы не найдены (English: Tables not found)

But this table exists and without a `-t` argument it works.

What is happening?

[image: Screenshot]

`\l` output:

> ProjectsManagement | postgres | UTF8      | Russian_Russia.1251 |
>   Russian_Russia.1251 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just taking a look at postgres documentation and samples I've found this specific case:

> To specify an upper-case or mixed-case name in -t and related
>   switches, you need to double-quote the name; else it will be folded to
>   lower case (see Patterns). But double quotes are special to the shell,
>   so in turn they must be quoted. Thus, to dump a single table with a
>   mixed-case name, you need something like:

```
$ pg_dump -t "\"MixedCaseName\"" mydb > mytab.sql
```

You can read about it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-EXAMPLES).

Comment: a hint to everyone using wildcards in such commands: you should place them **out of** double quotes like this `pg_dump --table="\"View_\"*" ..` (to dump all tables/views with names starting with `View_`)

Answer (score 3):

if the table's name is not all lower-case, you need to double-quote it, and then single quote the whole schema.table as well, with either `'"Statuses"'` or `'public."Statuses"'`:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d "ProjectsManagement" -t '"Statuses"' -a > path

pg_dump -U postgres -d "ProjectsManagement" -t 'public."Statuses"' -a > path
```

The above is for Linux/Unix systems. Windows command line has different behaviour regarding quoting and escaping special characters. So the following (or some of them) work but I'm not sure which is best and safest:

```
 -t "public.""Statuses"""           -- works
 -t "public.\"Statuses\""           -- works
 -t "public.^"Statuses^""           -- NO


 -t public."""Statuses"""           -- works
 -t public."\"Statuses\""           -- works
 -t public."^"Statuses^""           -- NO
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50037/discussion-between-ypercube-and-).